# deriving a formula for the integral of $[x]$ from 0 to n

Tags: integration, solution-verification

I'm trying to derive a formula for

$$\int_0^n [x]dx$$

by looking at the graph it's obvious I have to sum all the naturals and remove one

so I got $$\frac{(n)(n+1)-2}{2}$$

but this is wrong, it actually is

$$\frac{(n)(n+1)-2n}{2}$$

where am I going wrong?

Edit:- This is to a) Show where I'm struggling
and b) to prove I don't just want a formula handed down from someone else.

For  the sake of argument let's consider

$$\int_0^3 \lfloor x \rfloor dx$$

which can be split into $$\int_0^1 0dx +\int_1^2 dx+ \int_2^3 2dx$$

which is just 2+ ((3-2))2 which is 4
applying the original formula I got, we get  5, but **This includes the sum with 1, so to eliminate that, I remove the one**

and the above is precisely what is confusing me , we just have to remove the one once why do we have to do so n times.

[image]

the area that I'm attempting to find is shaded in green-purple
and green-purple-black, the sum obviously doesn't involve one which is why I'm trying to remove that alone

I would also like to apologise to the following users :- Lulu,
JonathanZ supports MonicaC, if they felt I was ghosting, I  had some other work, hence I couldn't reply earlier.

Edit 2:- Thanks to lulu for all the help, this is proof, with an added explanation for any future visitors to this page
$$\int_0^n [x]dx$$

now by taking any number of examples we see that the first term is always zero

now to find the sum  we want to add up the first n terms, however, and this is important, **only n-1** of these terms are natural
thus we arrive at the formula
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i= \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140409/discussion-on-question-by-math-and-physics-forever-deriving-a-formula-for-the-in).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lulu for all the help, this is a proof, with an added explanation for any future visitors to this page
$$\int_0^n [x]dx$$

now by taking any number of examples we see that the first term is always zero

for instance $$\int_0^2 \lfloor x \rfloor dx =0 +1$$

similarly $$\int_0^3  \lfloor x \rfloor dx = 0+1+2$$
observe how if we want to find the integral up to n, we only need to add the first (n-1) numbers.

now to find the sum  we want to add up the first n terms, however, and this is important, **only n-1** of these terms are natural
thus we arrive at the formula:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i= \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}$$

edit:- Corrected the final formula as I used the wrong summation expression earlier.

Comment: One comment:  Don't use the same letter to denote more than one thing.  In your last equation, you use $n$ to mean both the upper limit of the integral *and* the dummy summation variable.  Much better to rewrite the left hand as $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k$ or the like.

Comment: ah yes, i'll do that

Comment: can I make this a community wiki? I don't want to earn reputation from this, as other helped me trememdouly in proving this

Comment: If this is how you understand it, then good. But for me the simplest description is "If you take $n$ consecutive integers, but start at $0$, then your end term is $(n-1)$, not $n$". The common name for what you did is a "fencepost error". It's worth reading up on them (Wikipedia is fine), and you will end up with @lulu's conclusion that you should always check your general formulas to see that they work out correctly for some small value where you can explicitly write out every term.